# Starting ELK through docker-compose doesn´t work error mounting

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to run ELK through docker-compose with TLS enabled , but I am getting the same error still when typing ***docker-compose up -d*** :

> Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container:
> failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create
> failed: unable to start container process: error during container
> init: error mounting
> "/run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Work/src/elk-tls-docker/secrets/certificates/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt"
> to rootfs at "/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.crt":
> mount
> /run/desktop/mnt/host/d/Work/src/elk-tls-docker/secrets/certificates/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.crt
> (via /proc/self/fd/9), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown: Are
> you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if
> the specified host path exists and is the expected type

here is my ***docker-compose.yml*** file

```
version: '3.5'

# will contain all elasticsearch data.
volumes:
  data:

secrets:
  ca.crt:
    file: ./secrets/certificate_authority/ca/ca.crt
  elasticsearch.keystore:
    file: ./secrets/elasticsearch.keystore
  elastic-stack-ca.p12:
    file: ./secrets/certificate_authority/elastic-stack-ca.p12
  elasticsearch.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key
  elasticsearch.cert:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt
  kibana.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/kibana/kibana.key
  kibana.cert:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/kibana/kibana.crt
  logstash.pkcs8.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/logstash/logstash.pkcs8.key
  logstash.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/logstash/logstash.key
  logstash.p12:
    file: ./secrets/keystores/logstash/logstash.p12
  logstash.cert:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/logstash/logstash.crt
  filebeat.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/filebeat/filebeat.key
  filebeat.cert:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/filebeat/filebeat.crt
  metricbeat.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/metricbeat/metricbeat.key
  metricbeat.cert:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/metricbeat/metricbeat.crt
  packetbeat.key:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/packetbeat/packetbeat.key
  packetbeat.cert:
    file: ./secrets/certificates/packetbeat/packetbeat.crt

services:
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    hostname: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: ${ELK_VERSION}
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      CONFIG_DIR: ${ELASTIC_DIR}/config
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xmx${ELASTICSEARCH_HEAP} -Xms${ELASTICSEARCH_HEAP}
      bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"
      discovery.type: single-node
    volumes:
      - data:${ELASTIC_DIR}
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:${ELASTIC_DIR}/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
    secrets:
      - source: elasticsearch.keystore
        target: ${ELASTIC_DIR}/config/elasticsearch.keystore
      - source: ca.crt
        target: ${ELASTIC_DIR}/config/ca.crt
      - source: elasticsearch.cert
        target: ${ELASTIC_DIR}/config/elasticsearch.crt
      - source: elasticsearch.key
        target: ${ELASTIC_DIR}/config/elasticsearch.key
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -s https://elasticsearch:9200 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 200000
        hard: 200000
    networks:
      - elk

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    hostname: kibana
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:${KIBANA_DIR}/config/kibana.yml:ro
    environment:
      CONFIG_DIR: ${KIBANA_DIR}/config
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      ENCRYPTION_KEY: ${XPACK_ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      KIBANA_URL: ${KIBANA_URL}
    secrets:
      - source: ca.crt
        target: ${KIBANA_DIR}/config/ca.crt
      - source: kibana.cert
        target: ${KIBANA_DIR}/config/kibana.crt
      - source: kibana.key
        target: ${KIBANA_DIR}/config/kibana.key
    healthcheck:
      test: curl -s https://kibana:5601 >/dev/null; if [[ $$? == 52 ]]; then echo 0; else echo 1; fi
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch

  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    hostname: logstash
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config/logstash.yml
      - ./logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:${LOGSTASH_DIR}/pipeline/logstash.conf
      - ./logstash/pipeline/metricbeat.conf:${LOGSTASH_DIR}/pipeline/metricbeat.conf
    environment:
      path.settings: null
      CONFIG_DIR: ${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx${LOGSTASH_HEAP} -Xms${LOGSTASH_HEAP}"
    secrets:
      - source: ca.crt
        target: ${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config/ca.crt
      - source: logstash.cert
        target: ${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config/logstash.crt
      - source: logstash.pkcs8.key
        target: ${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config/logstash.pkcs8.key
      - source: logstash.key
        target: ${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config/logstash.key
      - source: logstash.p12
        target: ${LOGSTASH_DIR}/config/logstash.p12
    networks:
      - elk
    ports:
    - "12201:12201/udp"
    - "5044:5044"
    - "5045:5045/tcp"
    - "5046:5046"
    - "9600:9600"
    - "5000:5000/tcp"
    - "5000:5000/udp"
    depends_on: 
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
  
  packetbeat:
    container_name: packetbeat
    hostname: packetbeat
    user: root
    build:
      context: packetbeat/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add: 
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
    command: packetbeat -e -strict.perms=false
    volumes:
      - ./packetbeat/config/packetbeat.yml:${PACKETBEAT_DIR}/packetbeat.yml:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      CONFIG_DIR: ${PACKETBEAT_DIR}/config
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx${PACKETBEAT_HEAP} -Xms${PACKETBEAT_HEAP}"
    secrets:
    - source: ca.crt
      target: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ca.crt
    - source: packetbeat.cert
      target: ${PACKETBEAT_DIR}/config/packetbeat.crt
    - source: packetbeat.key
      target: ${PACKETBEAT_DIR}/config/packetbeat.key
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - logstash

  metricbeat:
    container_name: metricbeat
    hostname: metricbeat
    user: root
    build:
      context: metricbeat/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    restart: unless-stopped
    cap_add: 
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - while true; do metricbeat -e; sleep 1; done
    volumes:
      - ./metricbeat/config/metricbeat.yml:${METRICBEAT_DIR}/metricbeat.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      CONFIG_DIR: ${METRICBEAT_DIR}/config
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx${METRICBEAT_HEAP} -Xms${METRICBEAT_HEAP}"
    secrets:
      - source: elastic-stack-ca.p12
        target: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/elastic-stack-ca.p12
      - source: ca.crt
        target: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ca.crt
      - source: metricbeat.cert
        target: ${METRICBEAT_DIR}/config/metricbeat.crt
      - source: metricbeat.key
        target: ${METRICBEAT_DIR}/config/metricbeat.key
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - logstash
      - kibana

  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    hostname: filebeat
    build:
      context: filebeat/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      sh -c "filebeat -e"
    volumes: 
      - ./filebeat/config/filebeat.yml:${FILEBEAT_DIR}/filebeat.yml:ro
    environment:
      CONFIG_DIR: ${FILEBEAT_DIR}/config
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx${FILEBEAT_HEAP} -Xms${FILEBEAT_HEAP}"
      ELASTIC_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
    secrets:
      - source: ca.crt
        target: ${FILEBEAT_DIR}/config/ca.crt
      - source: filebeat.cert
        target: ${FILEBEAT_DIR}/config/filebeat.crt
      - source: filebeat.key
        target: ${FILEBEAT_DIR}/config/filebeat.key
    ports:
      - "9000:9000" 
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - logstash

  elastic-agent:
    container_name: elastic-agent
    hostname: elastic-agent
    build:
      context: elastic-agent/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      FLEET_CA: '/ca.crt'
      ELK_VERSION: ${ELK_VERSION}
      KIBANA_HOST: "https://kibana:5601"
      ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME: ${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: "https://elasticsearch:9200"
      FLEET_ENROLL_INSECURE: 1
      ENROLL_FORCE: 1
      PREFLIGHT_CHECK: 1
    secrets:
      - source: ca.crt
        target: /ca.crt
    ports:
      - "22:22" 
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - logstash

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my .env file:

```
ELK_VERSION=7.16.0
ELASTIC_USERNAME=elastic
ELASTIC_PASSWORD=changeme
KIBANA_URL=https://0.0.0.0:5601

# Configuration Variables
ELASTICSEARCH_HEAP=2g
LOGSTASH_HEAP=1g
PACKETBEAT_HEAP=250m
FILEBEAT_HEAP=250m
METRICBEAT_HEAP=250m
XPACK_ENCRYPTION_KEY=ert24tzzuuuuiolo

# Self signed TLS certificates
CA_PASSWORD=changeme
CA_DAYS=3650
ELASTIC_DIR=/usr/share/elasticsearch
LOGSTASH_DIR=/usr/share/logstash
KIBANA_DIR=/usr/share/kibana
PACKETBEAT_DIR=/usr/share/packetbeat
FILEBEAT_DIR=/usr/share/filebeat
METRICBEAT_DIR=/usr/share/metricbeat

# Letsencrypt certificates
## Setting STAGING to true means it will generate self-signed certificates
## Setting STAGING to false means it will generate letsencrypt certificates
# STAGING=false
STAGING=true

# swag Configuration
DOMAIN=mydomain.com
SUBDOMAIN=kibana
SUBFOLDER=kibana
EMAIL=email@email.com
TIMEZONE=America/Chicago
```